# Centering div both vertically & horizontally without messing the div animation?

Tags: html, css

I know this issue has been discussed on other threads. However, I haven't found a working solution for the problem that I have is a bit different (maybe, if I am mistaken, sorry, I am still a junior at CSS).

So, I was trying to make a dummy website, where when you hover the mouse over the image at the center, it will flip horizontally and show you the content.

FLIP ANIMATION CREDITS TO **David Walsh**: https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

HTML Code:

```
<div id="websitebackground">
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="flipper" >
            <div class="front" >
                <!-- front content --> 
               <img class="logocenter" src="images.svg" />
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                <!-- back content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#websitebackground
{
    min-height: 100vh; 
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-color: #34495e;
}

.logocenter {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

/*the rest flip animation is the same*/
```

How do I move the div to the middle? horizontally, vertically and also responsive, also without messing the animation.

I managed to center the div. However, the animation was a mess. the flip position is not where it should be. I want the image to keep positioned like this when it was flip or not:

http://www.corelangs.com/css/box/img/div-vertical-center.png

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - centering in CSS is tricky, 
[learn here how to do it properly](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/).

In your case I would use Flexbox approach, so:

### 1. Center with Flexbox.

```
#websitebackground
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-color: #34495e;
}
```

Also remember to change flip-containers size, to the size of your image, in my case it's 100x100px, so:

### 2. Set the proper size of your animated element.

```
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

### 3. Check the demo.

https://jsfiddle.net/m7wsLsnk/

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes thank you! it certainly works! I rarely use Flexbox. Appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your project does not require legacy browser fallback, the simplest and fastest way to do this is using **[Flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

Sample code (you will have to apply all types of **[prefixes](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)** in order for it to perform well on all browsers)

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Where `.container` would be `#websitebackground` or whichever the flipping element's parent is.

Comment: I just tried this. However, it does not work properly. the image was only slightly moved to the right (not to the center).

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a working example I shall give it a good guess. This hack should center any element inside a container with the class `.center-child`. Be sure that the container should only have one child.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div id="websitebackground">
    <div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
        <div class="center-child">
            <div class="flipper">
                <div class="front">
                    <!-- front content -->
                    <img class="logocenter" src="images.svg" />
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <!-- back content -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Additional CSS:**

```
.center-child {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.center-child:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    // Adjusts for spacing
    margin-right: -0.25em;
}

.center-child > * {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it certainly moved to center. However, when it flips, it goes back to the original place. Sorry that I did not provide a demo.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the awnsers given are wrong. Flexbox is not supported by IE under 10 and android browsers, neither is view width and height. So I advise you to do the following:

**HTML**

Wrap the img in a container:

```
<div class="img-cont>    
    <img class="logocenter" src="images.svg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

Give the container 100% width and height (relative on the container of 'img-cont'), and give 'img-cont' a pos absolute. Then u can give the animation a margin 0 auto.

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-cont {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.flip-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**And some JS**

Basically calculate the height of the page and placing the element in the center. Keep in mind that you might want to subtract the height of the element like so: 'var halfTop = ((site.height - parseInt($(el).height())) / 2) - 60;' (just an example)

```
var site = {
    resize: function() {
        // reset height and width
        site.width = parseInt($(window).width());
        site.height = parseInt($(window).height());

        $('.img-cont').each(function() {
            var el = $(this);

            var halfTop = ((site.height - parseInt($(el).height())) / 2);
            $(el).css('top' + halfTop + 'px');
        });

};

$(window).resize(function() {
    site.resize();
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I used chrome for testing. I'll try this solution.